# windows 10 on laptop with dual AMD graphics with one card is legacy

Tags: drivers, windows-10, integrated-graphics, amd-catalyst, dual-gpu

I've an hp laptop with dual graphics cards, iGPU is 45xx which belongs to legacy driver and dGPU is 54xx, which belongs to current version. Legacy and current version of drivers are incompatible. So before installing windows 10, I want to know if this setup will work in windows 10 or not?

Currently I'm using windows 7 with driver version before splitting.

Comment: No; I suggest getting rid of the legacy card

Comment: Legacy is IGP (on-board) so can't remove it.

Comment: You should use iGPU to indicate that unit, not IGP, which is the reason I didn't understand.  You can disable the device though.  I would dare say that is what you are doing know even on Windows 7 provided you are using the current drivers for it.  Even your dedicated (dGPU) card might have capability problems due to its age.

Comment: No, I'm not using current driver, I'm using older version of driver release before splitting, about 2 yrs old. 
When I don't need dGPU, I disable it from Catalyst control panel.